# In react package.json file, do I install @capacitor/android as dev dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json, capacitor

I am wondering if it is more appropriate to install `@capacitor/android`, `@capacitor/ios`, `@capacitor/core` as dev dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package probably needs to be included in the build. I would not install it as a dev  dependency.
In their Github's Readme file, they prompt you to use `npm install @capacitor/android` `npm install @capacitor/core` ,etc. Usually if the package can be installed as a dev dependency, they specify it in this command. (`--save-dev or -D`).